# Responsive header// resize img and the text over img

Tags: css, dom, responsive-design

I need img and text to resize based on div size// screen size. text should not get out of img on resize. I also tried with object-fit atribute and it doesn't work. Please help!!!

```
    <div class="row" id="bannerDiv">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="img/10045731_open-space-office.jpg" alt="banner">
      <div id="bannerText">
         <h3>Live webinar</h3>
         <h1>Veeam Virtual Labs: Begginer to Advanced</h1>
      <input type="button" id="regButton" value="REGISTER NOW">
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: `object-fit` applies to _replaced_ elements only. If you need this for static text, then you could figure out the font-sizes suitable for different break points manually via a bit of trial & error; if you need this for dynamic text, then you will need a JS solution that “measures” what font-size fill fit.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use absolute positioning for the text and button. You may want to change the font size of the header using a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

```css
#bannerDiv {
position: relative;
}
#bannerText {
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row" id="bannerDiv">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/900x300" alt="banner">
  <div id="bannerText">
    <h3>Live webinar</h3>
    <h1>Veeam Virtual Labs: Begginer to Advanced</h1>
    <input type="button" id="regButton" value="REGISTER NOW">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As we are not sure if you can use scss/mixins for media queries or if you can use JS i will provide jquery solution that may give you a hint but without the rest of your code , I can't do better. Fiddle would be nice .

```
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px)').matches) {
  //do something with the text or image
}
```

Comment: Thats a lot of code . Ok so try getting that text that is next to an image to float right .. `text { float: right}`   ...lets see what happens

Comment: I tried but the text is just the same only it's behind img now

Comment: ok than the flex is needed here . https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ Check this website . It is great for FlexBox

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful!